# Python arithmetic(float) operation

Tags: python, floating-point

When i type in the below in python i got the outputs as shown:

```
>>> a=1/3
>>> b=1/3
>>> c=1/3
>>> d=a+b+c
>>> d
1.0
>>> f=1-(1/3)-(2/3)
>>> f
1.1102230246251565e-16
>>> g=1-(1/3+2/3)
>>> g
0.0
>>>
```

if `d` value is `1.0` and `g` is `0.0` then why `f` value is not `0.0`?

Comment: Why the matlab tag?